# C++ stl for_each() and functor, where does it create new objects

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I am new to functor. Could anyone explain to me, in the following codes, when does the program create objects for AddValue class for each element of the vector? For me, what for_each() function should do is to get an element from vec first, and then create a new AddVal obj using this value (obj.i=value) and then call the functor AddVal(20) to add 20 to i and print it. But I didn't see where the creating new objects process happen. Thank u.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
class AddVal{
        public:
        int i;
        AddVal(int x) : i(x) {}
        void operator () (int val) {std::cout << val+i << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
        std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),AddVal(20));
}
```

Comment: This sounds like homework:(   Where did the code come from, and what have you done yourself to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddVal(20)` creates a single `AddVal` object passed in as the third argument to `for_each`. `for_each` then evaluates this object on each element of the vector. The code is somewhat equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
AddVal add_val(20);  // create the AddVal object
for (const int& i : vec) {
  add_val(i);  // calls AddVal::operator()
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. How come AddVal(20) creates a AddVal object first before the for_each loop? Because the constructor needs a parameter to initialize the member value i of the object. Do you mean it first create a object without initializing it? I never saw creating an object without initialization if the constructor takes in parameters.

Comment: @daydayup: What do you think the 20 is, if not a parameter to the constructor?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley. Oh I suddenly realized this. I thought it has to take in the element of the vector first and then add 20 to it; now it is adding the vector to 20; it is the same.

Answer (score 4):

```
for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),AddVal(20));
//                                ^
//                           right here
```

`AddVal(20)` creates a temporary `AddVal` object, calling the constructor `AddVal(int x)`, and passing 20 as an argument to that constructor. The `for_each` algorithm then uses the `operator()` from this object (or a copy of it) on each element of `vec`.